# Cannot pass values into a php function

Tags: javascript, php

I am having trouble passing in a value or array of values into my php script. When the submit button on the page is clicked, the following function executes:

```
$('#rangeSubmit').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://.../test.php',
            data: {test1:"DONE"},
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#myDiv").html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

The PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php

    echo $argv[1]; //should return the first item in the array of values passed to the php function?
    var_dump($_SERVER['argv']);

?>
```

And this script just returns "NULL" instead of the value I sent to the script. Any ideas?

Comment: Your values will be stored in `$_POST`

Comment: there is no PHP function present

Comment: An AJAX request is a regular HTTP request, it's exactly the same as typing the URL into the browser's address bar. You wouldn't usually use `$argv` either, would you?

Comment: Dude argv are null unless the page has arguments passed on command line, simple logic!! That's why argv in this case will always return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$argv[1] is a reference to parameter passed from command line, like:

```
php page.php argument
```

This call page.php with "argument" as parameter than can acessible with $argv[1].

To get post variables use $_POST[$name]. In your case use:

```
echo $_POST['test1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

try ;)

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['test1'];    
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$_POST['test1'];` in `test.php` to receive value passed through jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty but may help, If your PHP install allows it, you could simply try using exec(). In your receiving script, extract the POST arguments and format them into a command string then pass that to exec() to run.

```
$filein =$_POST[$arg1];
$fileout =$_POST[$arg2];

$return=exec("php target.php -i $filein -o $fileout ");
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `POST`

```
type: 'POST', --->POST REQUEST

var_dump($_POST['test1']);
```

Comment: there is no `argv` present

Comment: @feroz, Tough crowd today, just up voted you. Good luck getting to 1k!